# Scala generate a collection of elements based on a number of required elements and a known first element

Tags: scala

Looking for an elegant `Scala` way to generate a collection of elements based on a number of required elements and a known first element.

For example:

```
def generateListOfData(numberOfElements: Int = 1): Seq[Data] = {
if(numberOfElements == 1)
   Seq(aData(id = id)) //aData is some builder
else 
   // generate a `Seq` of elements with `id = randomInt`
}
```

What would be the most elegant approach to do it?

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly, you have the number of elements the collection must have and you want the first element to always be a constant value while the remaining ones are random, is that right?

Comment: Yes, the rest have a random field (let's say they use aData method to create the element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) is your friend.
You can use `tabulate` to get the results you want.

```scala
def generateListOfData(numberOfElements: Int = 1): Seq[Data] =
  Seq.tabulate(numberOfElements) { n =>
    if (n == 1) aData(id = id) else aData(id = randomInt)
  }
```

You may also use `fill` like this:

```scala
def generateListOfData(numberOfElements: Int = 1): Seq[Data] =
  aData(id = id) :: List.fill(numberOfElements - 1)(aData(id = randomInt))
```

PS: If `numberOfElements` is not positive the above methods will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks, the second one is a bit wrong, as it will always return a list larger by 1.

Comment: @Johnny ups... I forgot to add a `- 1`, I just edited my answer, and thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Yeah, just wanted it to be 100% for the next generation :)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate range from `1` to `numberOfElements - 1` map it into `Data` and prepend with default element:

```scala
def generateListOfData(numberOfElements: Int = 1): Seq[Data] = {
    if (numberOfElements > 0) {
      val rnd = new scala.util.Random
      aData(id = id) +: (1 to numberOfElements - 1)
        .map(_ => aData(id = rnd.nextInt()))
    }
    Seq[Data]()
}
```

Or using `foldLeft` and pattern matching with guards:

```scala
def generateListOfData(numberOfElements: Int = 1): Seq[Data] = {
    val rnd = new scala.util.Random
    numberOfElements match {
      case _ if numberOfElements > 0 => (1 to numberOfElements - 1)
        .foldLeft(Seq(aData(id = id))) { (acc, _) => aData(id = rnd.nextInt()) +: acc }
        .reverse
      case _ => Seq()
    }
}
```